# Django social network application - database schema

Tags: python, performance, database, django

I am writing a simple social media application in Django. I would like to know whether the following model structure is correct, or how can I improve the schema to get better performance. Do I need to split the **following** relation into a separate model? Like in [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/153710/sql-database-for-a-social-network)

**Models.py**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """
    Custom user model with email as username
    """
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=True, null=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(validators=[validate_dob],
                                     blank=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    avatar = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    followers = models.ManyToManyField("self", blank=True,
                                       symmetrical=False,
                                       related_name='following')

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    @property
    def age(self):
        current_year = datetime.datetime.today.year
        return current_year - self.date_of_birth.year

    def get_full_name(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first_name, self.last_name)

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=144)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    published_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['published_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

To prepare the feed for a requested user, I would like to use the query,

```
u1 = User.objects.first()
posts = Post.objects.filter(author__in=u1.following.all())
```